# What is a comoving basis?

Tags: differential-geometry, vector-spaces

I have read that the tangent vector, principal normal vector and binormal vector consistute a comoving orthogonal basis. But in this context what does comoving mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That would be the Frenet Frame I believe. At any point on a regular curve in $\mathbb{R}^3$ there are three vectors associated to that point, namely, the tangent, principal normal and binormal. These three vectors are orthogonal (orthonormal actually), and completely characterize the curve along which the "particle" moves. The frame can thus be considered as a "moving" basis moving along the particle on the curve (See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frenet%E2%80%93Serret_formulas, there they have animations of the Frenet Frame, so that you can literally see what "comoving" means).